# Проверка ссылки

Tags: java, java-ee, url

Как проверить ссылку является ли она изображением или zip или exe файлом? Пытался через getContentType(). Но что то не получается, результат не правильный. И нужно учитывать то, что у изображений куча форматов.

Часть кода

```
 URLConnection connection = new URL(link).openConnection();
       connection.getContentType().startsWith("image/jpeg")..............
```

Comment: Код-то покажите ...

Comment: @LexHobbit часть кода добавил в вопрос

Comment: ваш код рабочий, только нужно его поправить

Comment: @LexHobbit можете подсказать как?

Answer (score 1):

Существуют две известные библиотеки для этого

- [Apache Tike](http://tika.apache.org)
- [Jmime magic](https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic)
- В Java 7 появился еще такой метод: [Files.probeContentType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path))
- [Mime utills](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)
- В JDK есть такой метод [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
InputStream input = new URL(link).openStream();
mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(input);
if (mimeType.startsWith("image/jpeg")..............
```

Comment: Я же говорю, что форматов изображений очень много. Или их всех записать в коллекцию,  а потом сравнивать с ними?

Comment: @desking тогда использование этого метода не подойдет, так как очень ограниченное число mime типов у него реализовано. Если не лень, можете сами начитывать и сравнивать с магическими числами первые N байт.